# Getting a Permission Denied Error When Trying to Copy Files

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, shutil, file-copying

I am trying to copy a file from entry box 1 to the location of entry box 2. I am getting an error:

```
File "File_Name\Shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile 
with open (dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 131] Permission Denied: "File_Path"
```

Here is what I am Passing:

```
def copy_command():
    copyfile(e1.get(),e2.get())
```

The source code is down below:

```
import tkinter
import threading
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from pathlib import Path
#from shutil import copyfile
from shutil import *


def open_file_01():
    name=askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/%User%/Documents", filetypes=(("Text Files","*.txt"),("Data Files","*.dbs"),
                                                                            ("PNG Files","*.png"),("JPEG Files","*.jpg"),
                                                                            ("PDF Files","*.pdf"),("ISO Files","*.iso"),
                                                                            ("DOCX Files","*.docx"),("Exel Files","*.xlsx"),
                                                                            ("CSV Files","*.csv"),("PowerPoint","*.pptx"),
                                                                            ("ZIP Files","*.zip"),("All Files","*.*")))
    e1.delete(0,END)
    e1.insert(0,name)

def open_file_02():
    dir=askdirectory()
    e2.delete(0, END)
    e2.insert(0,dir)

def copy_command():
    copyfile(e1.get(),e2.get())

main=Tk()
main.configure(background='grey95')
main.title("temporary")
width = 500
height = 175
screen_width = main.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = main.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)
main.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))
main.resizable(0, 0)

#File Menu
menu = Menu(main)
new_item = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
new_item.add_command(label='Quit', command=main.destroy)
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=new_item)
main.config(menu=menu)

#Schedual
menu2 = Menu(main)
new_item = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
menu.add_command(label='Scheduale')
main.config(menu=menu)

l1=Label(main, text="From:")
l1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=(20,6))
l2=Label(main, text="To:")
l2.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=6)

from_dir=StringVar()
e1=Entry(main, width=50, textvariable=from_dir)
e1.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=(20,6))
to_dir=StringVar()
e2=Entry(main, width=50, textvariable=to_dir)
e2.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=6)

b1=Button(main, text="Browse...", width=10, command=open_file_01)
b1.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=6, pady=(20,6))
b2=Button(main, text="Browse...", width=10, command=open_file_02)
b2.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=6, pady=6)

b3=Button(main, text="Start", width=10, command=copy_command)
b3.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=3, pady=6)

pb=ttk.Progressbar(main, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=400, value=100)
pb.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2)

b4=Button(main, text="Cancel", width=10)
b4.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=2, pady=6)

main.mainloop()
```

Do I need to use a different method, or am I just using this one wrong?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: the bottom line is exactly what the error is telling you: you don't have permission to do what you want. That could mean exactly that, or it could mean that you're  copying the file to a different place than you think you are. Have you done any debugging to verify that `e1.get()` and `e2.get()` are returning what you think they are returning? Have you accounted for the fact the paths may be relative to the wrong starting point?

Comment: I am aware that the permission is denied. I am the administrator on my own machine. Besides having an invalid file path (Which is Valid), is there something different i can do to give the program permissions to copy the file? or is there a better method for this task?

Comment: If you're certain the file paths are correct, then you need to change the permission on the folder where you're trying to copy the file.

Comment: Looks like you have placed the file in an admin path. Try placing it on any other folder and don't forget to change the path in the code.

Comment: Proper permissions are on each folder, and nothing should be blocking the transfer. Wen I do a `print(e1.get())` and a `print(e2.get())`, It returns the actual path I have specified.

Comment: I have tried the `copyfileobj` method, and im returning a `'str' object has no attribute 'read'` error.

Comment: python and/or the OS won't lie to you. If it says you don't have permission, you don't have permission.

Comment: what happens if you manually run the copy command from a command prompt with the paths you get when you print the values of `e1.get()` and `e2.get()`?

Comment: If I run it through the command line, it works just fine. Just not through the script

Comment: Ok, this is a stupid resolution. Had to get rid of the `shutil`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change it from e1 and e2 to from_dir and to_dir, I also had to get rid of the `shutil` in front of `shutil.copyfile`.

```
def copy_command(buffer_size=16000):
        src=from_dir.get()
        dest=to_dir.get()
        copy(src, dest)
```